# How to award extra reputation for an answer?

Tags: support, reputation

What is the mechanism for awarding extra reputation to an answer?

Comment: Ask @PauloCereda: He will activate the voting squad ;-)

Comment: @Christian: ooh the Voting Squad. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda reporting as ordered, sir.

Comment: @Sean: Fire at will, commander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system is network wide so can't be changed just for tex.sx, so you'd need to raise a change request on the main meta. Note that one user known for offering "2000 point" bounties does that by awarding bounties of 500 points on *different* questions.....

So if you want to bump someone by 75 points, choose any good answer of theirs and give them 75. You can give a bounty giving the standard reason **Reward existing answer**. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices

Answer (score 11):

If you are willing to offer some of your own reputation for a correct answer, [set a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: There was a bounty. It was awarded automatically. Next bounty has to have double of the original bounty points. So there is a dilemma.

Comment: @Maesumi why is that a dilemma? it's just how the site works.

Comment: @Maesumi take care that even if only half of the bounty is awarded, you still 'pay' the full bounty amount.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The bounty award period after the conclusion of the 7 day period is only 24 hours. I think this is too short, given the possibility that some folks might submit late in the game. In my case (which I admit is rare to warrant further action) I was on the road while the time to assign the bounty ran out. There was originally a 150-point bounty. Half was awarded (somehow to the answer with lower points) and I just wanted to award same 75 points from my reputation to the other person. But the award system requires 300 new bounty.  etc etc.

Comment: @Maesumi the system is network wide so can't be changed just for tex.sx, so you'd need to raise a change request on the main meta. Note that one user known for offering "2000 point" bounties does that by awarding the bounties on _different_ questions..... so if you want to bump someone by 75 points, choose any good answer of theirs and give them 75.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I give the 75 points? If I set a bounty then I am inviting folks to work on something for which they won't get any points.

Comment: @Maesumi you can give a bounty giving the standard reason **Reward existing answer** see  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is what I was looking for. So If you convert your comment to an answer then that is the one I choose as accepted.

Answer (score 11):

According to the help center reputation are gain in particular for:

> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)

So you can add a [bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) as @smpl suggests in his answer.

But you may also want to accept answer which gave 15 rep points to the answer's OP. This enables one to track easily the answer that the OP judges the more useful.